# UITapGestureRecognizer causes app to crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, uitapgesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

UITapGestureRecognizer causes app to crash when a swipe is done. Swipes done over very short distances do not cause any problems, but those done over a longer distance give the error :

```
 -[UITapRecognizer name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ee27c0
```

where 0x17ee27c0 is a random value.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapRecognizer name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ee27c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2cb7dc1f 0x3a328c8b 0x2cb83039 0x2cb80f57 0x2cab2df8 0x2feee1c1 0x2d7d01cf 0x3024822d 0x300671ad 0x30066bcd 0x3003d3dd 0x302b0c29 0x3003be39 0x2cb44377 0x2cb43787 0x2cb41ded 0x2ca90211 0x2ca90023 0x33e890a9 0x3009c1d1 0xdca87 0x3a8a8aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

UITapRecognizer * (0x17ee27c0) is from tapGestureRecognizer._imp

This is happening on multiple devices running iOS 8.1 . The source is compiled on Xcode 6.

Here is how I declare the UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

And here is the method:

```
- (void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender { }
```

The UITapGestureRecognizer is placed on a SKView;

Here is the stack trace:
http://imageshack.com/a/img903/3622/X9QFX0.png

Comment: That was the way it was initially but I add it in an attempt to remove the error (I tried implenting gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: ) but it didn't work.

Comment: Where is the exception stack trace?

Comment: Here is the stack trace: http://imageshack.com/a/img674/6647/k76Dpi.png

Comment: Where is the stack trace that was displayed in the console before the exception was rethrown?

Comment: @AndreiArdelean please [set an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/74815) to get a useful stack.

Comment: It should be noted that the error was on UITapRecognizer, not UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: We need to see the exception stack.

Comment: This is the stack seen using a exception breakpoint : http://imageshack.com/a/img903/3622/X9QFX0.png

Comment: It would be better if you copied that stack, in "code" form, into your question.  That is how a question of this nature should be constructed from the start.

Comment: Your problem has to do with how you set up an SKNode.  I'm not familiar with that stuff, though, so I can't hazard a guess what you may have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in one of my SpriteKit Games, it is caused when you use gestures during transition between scenes, i solved it by setting `gestureRecognizer.enable` property ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/enabled)) to `NO` before the transition.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to run a selector called `name` on a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance, but `UITapGestureRecognizer` doesn't have such a selector and that's why your program is crashing. Check where you are calling `name` (probably inside `viewTapped`) and make sure you are applying it on the correct object.

Comment: Or it's a zombie object.

Comment: I thought of that but there isn't a single method call to name in my hole project. And viewTapped isn't even called.

Comment: I also looked for zombies but it was in vain.

Comment: Actually, he's trying call `name` on a UITapRecognizer, which is an entirely different beast.

Comment: @HotLicks this issue just is in ios 10 but in ios 13 is worked well, how solved in ios 10? i need use Name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `ViewTapped:` is expecting an argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cast as example: `action as MyTapGesture`

```
var gestureRecognizer = new MyTapGesture((action) =>
            {
                myEvent(action as MyTapGesture);
            });
            gestureRecognizer.Name = name;
```

and the class MyTapGesture be reemplazed to UITapGestureRecognizer

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace ETracker.Libraries
{
    public class MyTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MyTapGesture()
        {
        }

        public MyTapGesture(Action<UITapGestureRecognizer> action) : base(action)
        {
        }
    }
}
```